# How to access a database (like MS Access or something) in Fujitsu COBOL?

Tags: database, ms-access, cobol

I'm looking for example code on how to connect to a ODBC database using Fujitsu COBOL.
I couldn't find any documentation on their site which was useful to me :-S.

Many thanks,

Yvan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here http://www.alchemysolutions.com/Support/NetCOBOL-Tutorials under ´Working with SQL/Databases´